# What is difference between qasm_simulator and ibmq_qasm_simulator?

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience, simulation

There are many ways how to simulate a quantum circuit on IBM Q. However, in partiuclar I am interested in a difference between `qasm_simulator` and `ibmq_qasm_simulator`.

In Qiskit, the former can be called with statement

```
processor = Aer.backends(name = 'qasm_simulator')[0]
```

while the latter with

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
processor = provider.backends(name='ibmq_qasm_simulator')[0]
```

I realized that `ibmq_qasm_simulator` sends jobs similarly to a real quantum processor, i.e. I see the job in Job pane in IBM Q environment. But this is not the case for `qasm_simulator`.

In list of services on IBM Q page I found out only one `qasm_simulator`. So, my question is how these two simulators differ?

Comment: All `Aer` backends are local backends (they run on your local machine) and all backends from `providers` are cloud based. Notice how you call `qasm_simulator` or `statevector_simulator` as `Aer.backends( <name>)` where as you would call `ibmq_qasm_simulator`  or any of the actual hardware as `provider.backends(<name>)`. But overall, they are the same in term of what they do. Do note that all cloud backends have a threshold of $8192$ shots where as 'qasm_simulator` (local simulator) can go up to $1,000,000$ shots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ibmq_qasm_simulator` performs the simulation on a classic computer on that resides on the cloud, whereas `qasm_simulator` does it locally on your computer and consumes your CPU.